# Unicorn, nginx and serving sitemap.xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have my rails app rendering sitemap.xml

I'm running unicorn on 8080 and nginx.

When I do `http://server:8080/sitemap.xml` I get the sitemap.

HOWEVER, when I do `http://server/sitemap.xml` I get a part of the sitemap.xml but not all of it.

Everything else is working just fine. Static files are serving up just fine as well.

I suspect it has to do with the size of the sitemap and its transfer between unicorn and nginx.

Has anyone encountered the same problem before? Suggestions?

Comment: Look for errors in nginx.log, are there any? I had this strange behaviour once and it cost me a lot of time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the following.

1- follow @sergei's suggestion above: check the error.log for nginx

2- In my case, I needed to grant access to the nginx user to the path where unicorn's proxy is storing the files for upstreaming. In my case, it was in `/opt/nginx/proxy_temp`
do the following: `chown -R nginx:nginx .` while in /opt/nginx/proxy_temp

3- make sure you have `user nginx;` in your `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` or wherever you have it.

Comment: haha :-) ... I've taken the habit of writing the solutions back here for future reference too :-)

Comment: Yup... You always end up having the same problems again and again and wonder how you solved them :-)